# Facebook style of notification in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook

I want to implement a feature in my android app, which will receive notifications messages from my remote server(php and mysql database) even if the app is not running.

All users of the app should be notified when there is a new insertion into the database on the remote server.

I actually want something like how the facebook notification works, when a notification is sent, users will receive the message and would have a column to send their comments on that particular notification message.

I would be grateful if someone could give the direction to go and if there are any links to it, i would appreciate much.

Comment: Last I knew, Google has Cloud to device messaging (C2DM), which you interact with via your PHP server, then Google would send messages to devices and your app have a broadcast receiver to get those messages. Alternatively, you could have a background service that runs all the time and polls your server for new messages.... Or, you could use C2DM to simply notify the app that there is a new message, then pull the server for the actual message.

Comment: Oh ok, please which way is better? Using the google cloud device messaging or using a background service that runs all the time and pools my server for the messages